# Create Modal Form with bootstrap (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to create a modal form with Boostrap, by this tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCEbp07hfLw
I do the same like in the video.. but when I open this page in Browser I get nothing.
I add the boostrap folders to the 'WebContent' Folder , and add link for them.
this is my code, what is the problem?

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<meta charset="windows-1255">
</head>
<title>Insert title here</title>

<body>

    <div class="modal" id="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>פתיחת קריאה</h3>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="span4"/><br>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="text" class="span4"/><br><br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn">Clear</button>
            </form>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should load jQuery **before** Bootstrap. Any errors in console? Also try to validate your HTML, the `head` is not right, why are closing it there?

Comment: ok thanks..I change it but it doesn't help.. 
I see in the page only the title :'Insert title here'
and white page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should insert jquery on top of bootstrap and you must only use one of the bootstrap js. You loaded the 2 versions and they can create conflit.

also you are closing the head tag before including the scripts. This is wrong

2 things you should check:

First add before closing the body tag the following:

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function() {$('#myModal').modal('show');});
</script>
```

Next, i believe you are missing some tags for the modal to work such as:

**(you are missing the divs with modal-dialog and modal-content)**

```
<div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: now this is the order, but it still don't show me the form:

<script
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: I updated my post. You are cloaing the head before inserting the acripts and links

Comment: thanks I updated my Post too, I change what you say, but nothing change.

Comment: See the source code (ctrl + u) and click on the jquery and bootstrap and see if they open correctly. Ifnot, they are not where you say they are. Please check

Comment: I have updated my response. I believe it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the effort to help me:)  
but I update the code (and check it on the Source code of the page) , and it still show me white page without any form/text ..

Comment: it has to work. i'm working fine with it. i have added to download: http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/487487/tests-zip.html